# Show that $f_n=n[f(x+1/n)-f(x)]\to f'$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be $C^1$ on $(a,b)$. Define $f_n=n[f(x+1/n)-f(x)]$. Show that $f_n\to f'$ uniformly on any closed interval $[c,d]\subset (a,b)$.

Showing the convergence is easy, but how to show that it is uniform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mean value theorem we can find $y=y(x,n)$ such that
$$
 f(x+1/n)-f(x) = \frac1n f'(y(x,n))
$$
and $|y(x,n)-x|<\frac1n$.
It follows that $f_n(x)= f'(y(x,n))$.

The uniform convergence follows by uniform continuity of $f'$ on the closed interval $[c,(d+b)/2]$.